# Updating second worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two worksheets in the same workbook and would like to auto populate the information from the original (worksheet1) to update (worksheet2) once a certain date has passed.

**For example:**
If a project's date has passed the information from "Original" will auto populate in worksheet two. Right now I am in a sense manually completing this task, by placing the information into A1 clicking on "Update".

The formula is below:

```
Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Update").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("Original").Select
    Range("A3").Select
```

What can I do to have it automatically placed into the "Update"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to throw that code into the Worksheet_Activated subroutine.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

 End Sub
```

[Additional Info Here](https://excel.tips.net/T002564_Running_a_Macro_when_a_Worksheet_is_Activated.html)